# Possibly Problem with Default Theme

Tags: themes

Hi I don't know what really happened but now menus and windows and some properties seems they don't have any padding.

I tried to change themes and seems that the theme "High Contrast" gives some padding, but "Ambiance"(default) and "Radiance" removes padding.

Also, I tried to repair packages.

[image]

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: You can write your own answer here of what you did to help others.  =)

Comment: solution for me:
'sudo apt-get install light-themes'
After the installation I Have chosen "Radiance Theme" and switch to Default Them again and it was fixed.

Comment: You can write that below as an answer and you can accept it.  I will give you an upvote for it.  This can help others that may be experiencing the same issues.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance, but where should i write? In the post or answer?

Comment: Move what you put in the question and move it to the answer.

Comment: Make sure you click on Answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution for me:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install light-themes
> ```
>
> After the installation I have chosen "Radiance Theme" and switch to default theme again and it was fixed.

<sub>Source: [A comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083032/possibly-problem-with-default-theme#comment1780331_1083032)</sub>